# How to view data from database that assigned to particular user in flask sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask

**1.**

How to make so that when user log in he/she can see the tickets only assigned to current_user?
I did the following:

**routes.py**

```
    @app.route('/')
def index():
    projects = Projects.query.all()
    tickets = Tickets.query.filter(Tickets.expert_id == current_user.id).all()
    return render_template('home.html', projects = projects , tickets = tickets)
```

But it doesn't return anything.
My model and database work perfectly and when query it, I can see that each user has tickets that assigned to them.

**2.**

I have three types of users

*1.Admin
2.Expert
3.Regular user (developer)*

I would like to make Admin and Expert to be able to see all the tickets while developers can only see tickets that assigned to them
so something like this:

```
    @app.route('/')
def index():
    projects = Projects.query.all()
    if curret_user.admin == 1 or current_user.expert == 1:
         tickets = Tickets.query.all()
    else:
        tickets = Tickets.query.filter(Tickets.expert_id == current_user.id).all()
    return render_template('home.html', projects = projects , tickets = tickets)
```

is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with databases, but I think `Tickets.query.filter` shouldn't take a boolean as an argument, because booleans don't change.

Comment: @David thanks for replying, so what should be then?

Comment: Well I'm really not good at databases... Sorry I couldn't help on that. @MuhammedTech